# It can take up to six hours for the app to appear in Outlook

Tags: outlook

Whenever I try to add an add-in in Outlook 2019 I get `Deployed. It can take up to six hours for the app to appear in Outlook`.
Is there any way to force/speed up this process? 6 hours seems like... a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to restart the outlook client and check if it takes effect?

In general, It takes up to 6 hours to take effect. And I have done some research, I cannot find anything to force add-ins taking effect immediately.

Comment: Restarting the client didn't help. At 9:37pm (well after 6 hours!) I got an email that the add-in had been successfully deployed.